# Using the Black-Scholes Equations to derive another equation

Tags: solution-verification, finance

Below is a problem I did. I believe my answer is right but I would like somebody to check it for me.

> **Problem:** Show that the Black-Scholes formula for call and put options satisfy put-call parity equation. The put-call parity equation is:
> $$ c + Ke^{-rT} = p + S_0 $$

We have:
\begin{align*}
c &= S_0 N(d_1) - Ke^{-rT}N(d_2) \\
p &= Ke^{-rT}N( -d_2) - S_0 N( -d_1 ) \\
c - p &= S_0 N(d_1) - Ke^{-rT}N(d_2) - \left(  Ke^{-rT}N( -d_2) - S_0 N( -d_1 ) \right)  \\
c - p &= S_0 N(d_1) - Ke^{-rT}N(d_2) - Ke^{-rT}N( -d_2) + S_0 N( -d_1 ) )
\end{align*}
Note that:
$$  N(d_1) +  N(-d_1) = 1 $$
\begin{align*}
c - p &= S_0 ( N(d_1) +   N( -d_1 ) ) - Ke^{-rT}N(d_2) - Ke^{-rT}N( -d_2) \\
c - p &= S_0 ( N(d_1) +   N( -d_1 ) ) - Ke^{-rT} ( N(d_2) + N( -d_2) ) \\
c - p &= S_0  - Ke^{-rT} \\
c + Ke^{-rT} &= p + S_0
\end{align*}

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.